# Why do I get a slow motion effect every time my cube collides with a wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

So I have this cube, which has rigid body movement, it moves forward at a constant speed and up, down, right, left on `button click`.

My problem is that whenever my cube hits the walls that I have it does a slow motion effect for two seconds and then back to normal speed.

**How do I prevent this slow motion effect from happening?**

Comment: What do you mean by 'slow motion effect'? (A video would help)  If it's only when colliders are touching you might want to look into physics materials (specifically, friction)

Comment: @Immersive I solved my problem, but thanks anyway :)

Comment: Nice work!  It's good practice here to add the solution you came up with to your own question. =)

Comment: I just tweaked the speed values, and it fixed it.

Comment: This is surely about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript]. Also, this is not a valid use for the [tag:visual-studio] tag.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic case of physics time lag. What's happening is your physics engine suddenly takes more time to calculate things because the cube is hitting something and this slows down your frame time, ultimately slowing down the movement.
Unfortunately the only way to improve this problem is to scale down everything so that the engine doesn't have to work as hard.